# an object reference is required for the non-static field method or property

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to use Textbox Id in the Sql query, but is shows above error.
When i Provide Customer Name instead of Customer Id then it works fine.

Here is my code..

```
  [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]

public static List<string> SearchAddress(string prefixText, int count)
{

   using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = dbConnection.fnConnectionString();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {             
            cmd.Connection = conn;

            conn.Open();

            cmd.CommandText = @"select city,Addresscode from BName_Addresscode
                           where Customer='"+txtCustomerName.text+'";

            List<string> customers1 = new List<string>();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {

                    String Code = sdr["City"].ToString();
                    String Name = sdr["Addresscode"].ToString();
                    Name = Code + "(" + Name + ")";
                    customers1.Add(Name);

                }
            }
            conn.Close();
            return customers1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Before you do anything else, [fix your SQL Injection risk](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

Comment: I do not see any Customer Id in your example. In which line you get error?

Comment: Why don't you pass `txtCustomerName.Text` value as a param to your `SearchAddress()` method via jQuery ajax call? I am assuming that's where the error is

Comment: @PablonotPicasso sorry , it is textbox id not customer id

Answer (score 1):

That won't work, here's why.

Your page method is **static**

```
public static List<string> SearchAddress(string prefixText, int count)
```

which means you can't refer to instance members, `txtCustomerName.Text` refers to the instance member of your class (`txtCustomerName`).

To fix this, move the actual textbox value to the **argument** of this method, interesting fact is that you possibly already have it there, the `prefixText` argument seems to be the one, doesn't it?

```
public static List<string> SearchAddress(string **prefixText**, int count)
```

Then, in your JavaScript, just pass the value to the method as described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-web-services#creating-and-using-page-methods):

```
function GetSearchAddress() 
{
    var customer = $get("txtCustomerName").value;
    var count    = ...;
    PageMethods.SearchAddress(customer, count, onCompleted);
}
```